# Click on panel causes asynchronous postback but click on children causes full page postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, dopostback

I have the following ASCX control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalendarDay.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="MVP.Calendar.CalendarDay" %>

<asp:Panel ID="DayWrapper" runat="server" 
    CssClass="day col p-2 border border-left-0 border-top-0 text-truncate">
    <div class="date d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center <%= CurrentDayTag %>">
        <%= DayText %>
    </div>
    <div class="row pl-3 pr-3 d-none d-sm-block">
        <p class="info"><%= InfoText %></p>
        <a class="d-block rounded small align-self-start" title="Test 1"><%= PriceText %></a>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here's part of its code-behind:

```
public partial class CalendarDay : UserControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        DayWrapper.CssClass += DayBackgroundTag;
        DayWrapper.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:__doPostBack('" + UniqueID + "', '')";
    }

    void IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        OnDayClicked();
    }
}
```

Here's the DOM that's rendered:

```
<div id="MainContent_CalDate_WeekRepeater_DayRepeater_3_CalendarDay_1_DayWrapper_1"
    class="day col p-2 border border-left-0 border-top-0 text-truncate day--fully-available"
    onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$CalDate$WeekRepeater$ctl03$DayRepeater$ctl01$CalendarDay', '')">
    <div class="date d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">17</div>
    <div class="row pl-3 pr-3 d-none d-sm-block">
        <p class="info"></p>
        <a class="d-block rounded small align-self-start" title="Test 1">10€</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This ASCX control is inside a rather complex hierarchy, but ultimately, all of this is inside an `UpdatePanel`.

On that rendered HTML, if I click on the 17 or on the 10€ text, I get a full page postback, but if I click anywhere else within the top div, I get an AJAX call from my `UpdatePanel`. **Both** these calls are triggering the `RaisePostBackEvent` function correctly.

I want and would expect to get the AJAX call every time.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd need to experiment with what you're doing but it looks like an `eventArgument` is required, but there's no argument. `__doPostBack` is passing a control, which would "map" to `__EVENTTARGET` (eventTarget), not argument. (?) Or is the empty argument enough?

Comment: @wazz The contents of `argument` are passed into `RaisePostBackEvent`. The `__EVENTTARGET` is indeed what distinguishes one instance of the control from another, and it's what I need for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to register the control for async postback. Try changing this;

```
DayWrapper.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:__doPostBack('" + UniqueID + "', '')";
```

To this:

```
DayWrapper.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this));
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
```

The main difference here the call to `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl` which tells the `ScriptManager` that the control should indeed be used for async postback. I am also changing the way that the postback link is generated. This might not actually be necessary, but it seems cleaner than manually generating the JavaScript.

Comment: No worries - I tested this out and it worked for me, so hopefully it will work for you too :)

Comment: I've just tested this and it works. Why it works is completely beyond me. The control is a child of an UpdatePanel. Clicking on the control's client area causes an async postback correctly. Why should I have to register the control in order to have the labels inside work correctly?

Comment: Incidentally, you were right. Changing the way the postback link is generated has no bearing on the issue, but the code is indeed cleaner.